# How to input images in rllib

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, rllib

last time I saw library rllib: https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/rllib/index.html.
It has amazing features for reinforcement learning, but unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to input images as an observation without flattening them (I basically want to use convolutional neural network). Is there any way to input image observations in models using rllib library?

Answer (score 1):

Rllib is compatible with openai's gym, you can create a custom env https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/rllib/rllib-env.html#configuring-environments and return a Box as an observation space like https://stackoverflow.com/a/69602365/4994352

Comment: yes but how can i use convolutional neural network in rllib model?

Comment: Does it use convolutional neural network automatically? i mean what if i want to change the architecture of model, can i pass arguments which will do that?

Comment: You need to write your own model which will use the layers you want

Comment: Ray is for higly distributed workload, are you looking for an automatic RL solution ?

Comment: yes, automatic, maybe i can pass string or something like that

Comment: Ok I see, so you can update your question with a definition of the problem you're trying to solve and I'll edit my answer if I can find a solution

Comment: I found out answer already, thank you for your effort

Comment: No problem, You can edit your question with the answer to help the rest of the community